# How to get population (count of civils) of the city with the Google API? Which requests should I use?

Tags: java, spring-boot, google-api

I'm developing a studying project in java spring-boot.

For example, the following request:

```
https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/geocode/json?address=Moscow&key=APP_KEY
```

finished with code 200 OK, and JSON response with
latitude, and longitude.

**Which request can provide information about the population of the city?**

Comment: That pretty clearly says your key doesn't have access to that API. Why don't you just come up with a project that uses the data you _do_ have?

Comment: I have a form where we register a new city. In this form needs to type latitude, longitude, population. This is boring for users.
I want to add the feature, that will be found automatically coordinates and population to be added to the object. So, the user should be input only the name of the city

Answer (score 0):

I resolve the problem by getting geocode. I just get enabled Geocoding API, and my key from Places Api was usable to Geocoding API.

Now question only how to get population due to Google API.